# Scraping data from highcharts using R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I'm trying to scrape the data contained in this highchart using R: https://modi.minerba.esdm.go.id/pimpinan/produksiPenjualan?t=2020

I've tried using html_nodes to target the data, but I can't make that work, maybe because it's in some javascript?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. In this case, we expect your own attempt at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. Please refer to this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I hope you have a good time here!

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what the problem is? Here you can find a reference to the highcharts R wrapper which you may find helpful: https://jkunst.com/highcharter/

Comment: Sorry yes, I would like to make a script to collect the data behind the chart. I can see where it is in the html i think, but don't know what to enter in html_nodes(xx) to isolate it      series: [{
            name: 'Realisasi Produksi (Juta Ton)',
            data: [51.37847243,46.95619187,51.66103887,44.26354522,41.96709551,46.49995221,44.42683935,48.38940033,43.9892341,46.32408666,47.41816291,37.83777055]